# Call class function by signal&slot system

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt so my question may be trivial. But I couldn't find proper answer or maybe I didn't really get the idea of signals & slots.

I have a `MainWindow` with four radio buttons and a class "Data" with no GUI representation. What I'm trying achieve is to set some property in class when radio button is checked.

Here is my header for class:

```
#include <QObject>

class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Data(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Data();

signals:

public slots:
    void setTextOrientation(int data);

private:
    int textOrientation;
};
```

Here is the constructor for `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    data = new Data();
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->textOrientRB0, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), &data, SLOT(setTextOrientation(int)));
}
```

and the error:

```
mainwindow.cpp:10: error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'Data **' to 'const QObject *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: Remove the '&' from data in the connect call. The connect takes a pointer to the object and you're passing a reference to that pointer.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html - you should read this if you don't understand signals and slot setup of Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QObject::connect` expects that the third argument is pointer to `QObject`. In your example you pass `&data` as third argument. `&data` is not pointer to `QObject`. It is pointer to pointer. Pass just `data` instead.
This should solve compile error.

May be there will be another run-time error, since `toggled` has one argument of type `bool` and `setTextOrientation` has one argument of type `int`.

For compiler time checking of signal/slot compatibility (compatibility of the 2nd and 4th parameter of `connect`) you can use following syntax:

```
QObject::connect(ui->textOrientRB0, &QAbstractButton::toggled, data, &Data::setTextOrientation);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Using `data` instead of `&data` solved the problem with compile error. But even then function was not called.
Solution was to use `connect(ui->textOrientRB0, &QAbstractButton::toggled, data, &Data::setTextOrientation)`. It has the limitation that it calls function setTextOrientation with arguments 0/1, but I will edit the code respectively to this.

Answer (score 2):

You passed pointer to pointer, instead of pointer, here :

```
connect(ui->textOrientRB0, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), &data, SLOT(setTextOrientation(int)));
```

it should have been :

```
connect(ui->textOrientRB0, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), data, SLOT(setTextOrientation(int)));
```

At least, this is what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

What does Data look like in the header file?  It looks like you're passing a pointer to a pointer to Data, when you need to pass it pointer to Data.

If data is indeed type Data*, then the call should be

```
connect(ui->textOrientRB0, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), data, SLOT(setTextOrientation(int)));
```

Would need to see the header file to be sure, but I assume it is based on it's initialization.